# is it possible to start activemq with a configuration file that's not in one of the default locations?

Tags: configuration, activemq-classic

All right all you activemq guru's out there...

Currently activemq require a configuration file before it runs.  It appears from its debug output message:

```
$ ./activemq start -h
 INFO: Using default configuration (you can configure options in one of these file: /etc/default/activemq      /home/user_name/.activemqrc)
```

That you can *only* put it in one of those two locations.  Anybody know if this is the case?  Is there some command line parameter to specify its location?

Thanks!
-roger-

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. Here are 3 possible answers.

If classpath is setup properly:

```
activemq start xbean:myconfig.xml

activemq start xbean:file:./conf/broker1.xml
```

Not using the classpath:

```
activemq start xbean:file:C:/ActiveMQ/conf/broker2.xml
```

reference: 
http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-command-line-tools-reference.html

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to find the answer to this and I struggled with this myself for a while, but I've found a bit of a workaround.  When you use bin/activemq create, you can create a runnable instance that will have its own bin, conf, and data directories.  Then you have more control over that runnable insance and the .activemqrc becomes less important.

See this for detail on the create option : http://activemq.apache.org/unix-shell-script.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`bin/activemq start xbean:/home/user/activemq.xml`

Note that if the xml file includes other files like jetty.xml then it needs to be in that dir also.

If using a recent 5.6 SNAPSHOT you can set the env var ACTIVEMQ_CONF to point to the location where you have the config files

Comment: I still see the message log in the console about specifying a config even when passing that "xbean:...". I'm using amq 5.5.1.

Comment: The configuration file referenced in the question is different from the activemq.xml config file.

Comment: -1 from me because that (xbean:/path/to/config) does not work.  It should not be the activemq.xml file, it should be the one that you generate with the setup.  That said, this just does not work.

Answer (score 0):

in the /bin/activemq script under # CONFIGURATION # For using instances, you can add or remove any file destinations you'd like.

Be very though since it ignores the others at the first occurrency of a file, read more here

[Unix configuration](http://activemq.apache.org/unix-shell-script.html)

happy coding !